# Issue: nesting flexboxes next and on top of each other

Tags: css, flexbox

I currently have a problem with nesting a flex box layout. I have a parent flex container and four separate containers within it, so far the other 3 column containers work correctly. However when I try to place another container underneath the main one it simply moves to the right side.

```css
.container-wrap {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container-leftbar {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  gap: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  flex: 1;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-width: fit-content;
}

.container-main {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  gap: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  flex: 1;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-width: fit-content;
}

.container-main2 {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  gap: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.container-rightbar {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  gap: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-width: fit-content;
}
```

```html
<!--flex wrap-->
<div class="container-wrap">
  <!--left column-->
  <div class="container-leftbar">
    <div class="1a">123</div>
    <div class="1b">123</div>
    <div class="1c">123</div>
  </div>
  <!--1 middle body-->
  <div class="container-main">
    <div class="2a">123</div>
    <div class="2b">123</div>
  </div>
  <!--2 middle body-->
  <div class="container-main2">
    <div class="3a">123</div>
    <div class="3b">123</div>
  </div>
  <!--right column-->
  <div class="container-rightbar">
    <div class="3a">123</div>
    <div class="3b">123</div>
    <div class="3c">123</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried to manually place the the top and left margin of the main box however I only really was able to achieve the top margin placing. I'm still somewhat new to using flex so any sort of help is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!, Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Please provide your HTML

Comment: Hi! sorry about that I updated the post with my rough html layout

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by `when I try to place another container underneath the main one`?

Comment: Are you trying to get this result? https://jsfiddle.net/r1bjpah8/1/